# PHP- Generate a gradient then pick a color depending on the "rank" value from database

Tags: php, html, algorithm, gradient

I have a table of users and a table of userdata. Both are connected with the primary key, I select the "rank" from userdata, and assign it to the user.
So, I want to print around 100 users at a single page, and need their nicknames to be colored depending on their rank. The rank varies from -int max to int max, but colors would only change from range -7000 to 7000.

I wanted the gradient to be red-black(in the middle)-green. 
Example of how it should work:
-Get user rank from database (already got this)
-Generate a gradient in memory or something like this
-Pick a value, for example if user has rank 3500, pick the position at 75% of the gradient, counting from left (middle is black)
-Color a span before the link using the color got before as hex value

Any ideas how can I do this fast enough so the php code doesn't compute too much?

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're asking how to optimize code that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed like this:

- Calculate user percentage score if score between -7000 and +7000 `$userPercentage = $userScore/7000` (if not between, set to -7000 if less or +7000 if more).
- Give each user's name a `style="color: rgb(x,y,0);"` property.

Use this code:

```
if($userScore < 0){
    percentage *= -1;
    echo('color: rgb('.255*$percentage.', 0, 0);');
} else {
    echo('color: rgb(0, '.255*(1-$percentage).', 0);');
}
```